# Adding parallax effect with fullPage's plugin

Tags: html, css, parallax, fullpage.js

I'm trying to add a parallax effect to a page i'm creating with vertical slides.

This is what I have so far:[image]

And this is what I'm trying to re-create. You can notice a slight parallax effect on the overlay text and the background image

[image]

My HTML sturcture looks like this:

this is the code for each section, which is nested in a div with an `id` of `fullpage`

```
        <div class="section">
            <div class="fp-bg">
                <div class="img1-container">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3 class="title">Mountain</h3>
                            <h1 class="caption">In the wild There is no healthcare</h1>
                            <p class="description">Healthcare is "Oh, I broke my leg!" A lion comes and eats you. You're dead. Well, I'm not dead. I'm the lion. You're dead.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the setting I have for the `fullpage` options object:

```
    <script>
        new fullpage('#fullpage', {
            licenseKey: 'OPEN-SOURCE-GPLV3-LICENSE',
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(.825,0,.5,1)',
            parallax: true,
            parallaxOptions: {
                    type: 'reveal',
                    percentage: 100,
                    property: 'translate'
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Amy I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the parallax options you are using on your fullpage.js initialisation you should be using the [parallax extension for fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html), which is a separate JavaScript file that needs to be included before fullPage.js. Note is is a paid extension tho.

[image]

You can read more about how to use it on the docs page:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/Extension---Parallax

Comment: Hey @Alvaro Do I need to pay to use this extension?

Comment: Yes. Extensions are not free. But think about it this way: you are supporting me (the author) and helping me to keep improving fullPage.js and all around it. (Or even creating new components)

Comment: I don't think this fits as an answer on StackOverflow. You're promoting your proprietary extension as a solution instead of answering the question.

Comment: It is actually the easiest solution to use parallax with fullpage.js. Yes, it is a paid extension, however I do still think it answers the question. And yes, I'm the author, but would it make any difference if someone else suggested it? 
I believe the whole point is providing a valid solution for a question. I've answered hundreds of questions regarding fullpage.js in stackoverflow and as always, just trying to help them with their issues. I don't think recommending a paid solution is out of topic in a case where it is exactly what they ask for. Just trying to help like in other cases.

Comment: The OP did provide code examples of what they've done in trying to achieve the effect. At the very least you could've tried to offer some solution or ideas based on the context of the codes provided, before straight up suggesting a proprietary solution.

Comment: Yeap, if your read his question you'll notice he is using the fullpage options `parallax: true` and `parallaxOptions`. Even the element `fp-bg` used by fullPage.js parallax extension. You can read about it on the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

So, I assume he read the docs but didn't realise he had to purchase the extension separately to use those options.

Comment: So answering his question `Amy I missing something here?`. Yes, he is. He is missing purchasing the extension to use those options and that markup. Recommending him another approach would be not really answer his question.

Comment: Okay fine. Maybe you could've phrased it better by saying the parallax option requires the parallax extension. It seemed like you were suggesting an alternative instead.